# Solving a matrix as a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}5 & 4 & -6\\-2 & -1 & 2\\2 & 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$$

how do I solve $x'=Ax$ as a differential equation? My text book explains this in a rather confusing way and I am really not getting it - what if I just found the eigen values - would the solution be anything to do with that or could I just use some kind of gaussian elimination?

Any help would be much appreciated, many thanks. :)

Comment: apart from those two answers, it is well explained on [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-23-differential-equations-and-exp-at/)

Comment: sorry i have now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the Eigenvalues, the main idea is that 
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{At}= A e^{At}$$ 
To compute $e^{At}$ you need the eigenvalues and their multiplicity, gaussian elimenation won't help you.

The Eigenvalues of your matrix are 
$$\sigma=\{ 1+2i,1-2i,1\}$$ 
and the eigenvectors are 
$$\begin{pmatrix}  2+i \\ - 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \quad \begin{pmatrix} 2-i\\ -1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \quad \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
So the system is an linear combination of $e^{\lambda_i t} v_i$.

Comment: so is each answer $e^At$ where A is an eigen value?

Comment: no $A$ is the matrix, do you know jordan normal form? the solutions will be a combination of eigen and main ( haupt?) vectors

Comment: im not sure i get it - jordan normal form hasnt been mentioned!

Comment: @user67411 added a bit

Comment: ah okay great i get that now! why couldnt my book say it like that?! So is that it? Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The solution to your differential equation is $$x(t) = e^{At}$$ where $e^{A}$ is defined as $$e^A = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{A^k}{k!}.$$ This infinite series can be evaluated by writing $A = PDP^{-1}$, the eigenvalue decomposition of A (assuming it exists), where $D$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues of $A$. For an example, see http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/linear-algebra/matrix-exponential/matrix-exponential.html.